# Create an adjacency list of strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, list, graph

I want to add an edge in my adjacency list using strings. 
Below is what I have so far. I read data from a file(void connections(string file)) , and I want to add an edge to the list. My files are all loaded and I get all the data but the edge is the problem.
We are to implement our own graph data structure and not use any library like list or maps
My display_AdjList(Node* h) method is also hard to implement with strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Populace{
    string p_name;
    int p_age;
    float p_spread_prob;
    float p_d_prob;
};

struct Node {
    string val;
    Node* next;
};

struct graphEdge {
    string start_ver, end_ver;
};



string name;
int age;
float prob;
class Graph{


    private:
    Node* getNode(string p, Node* head){
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->val = p;

        newNode->next = head;   
        return newNode;
    }
    int N;
    graphEdge edge[];
    Populace *person; 


public:

    Node **head;                
   Graph(int N)  {
        head = new Node*[N]();
        this->N = N;
        person=new Populace[N];



    }


    void read_from_file(string file){
        ifstream fil;
        string info;
        int i;
        fil.open(file.c_str());
        while (fil>>name>>age>>prob)
        {

                getline(fil,info);
                person[i].p_name=name;
                person[i].p_age=age;
                person[i].p_spread_prob=prob;
                i++;    
                }
            }


    int index(string h){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            if(h==person[i].p_name){
                return i;
            }
                    }

    }

    void con_add(string start, string end){

        int star=index(start);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
            head[i] = nullptr;

            for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
                 start=edge[i].start_ver;
                 end= edge[i].end_ver;


                Node* newnode=getNode(end,head[star]);

                head[star]=newnode;
            }
        }
    }


    void connections(string file){
        ifstream fil;
        string info;
        int i;
        string start_ver,end_ver;
        fil.open(file.c_str());
        while (fil>>start_ver>>end_ver){
            getline(fil,info);
            cout<<start_ver<<","<<end_ver;
            cout<<endl;
            con_add(start_ver,end_ver);
             }
            }





    void print_population(){
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cout<<person[i].p_name<<" ";
            cout<<person[i].p_age<<" ";
            cout<<person[i].p_spread_prob<<endl;
        }
    }

     ~Graph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        delete[] head[i];
        delete[] head;
     }


void display_AdjList(Node* h)
{
     string m;


     for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        m=person[i].p_name;
         while (h != nullptr) {
                 cout << "(" << m << ", " << h ->val
            << ", " << ") ";
       h = h->next;
              }
    }
    cout << endl;
     }




};
int main()
{

    int N = 9;      
    int i;
   Graph diagraph(N);
        diagraph.read_from_file("smallpopulation.dat");
        diagraph.print_population();
        diagraph.connections("smallconnections.dat");
        diagraph.display_AdjList(diagraph.head[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does  "create an edge between them" mean? There's no such thing as an "edge" in C++. C++, the programming language, consists of basic native types, classes, templates, functions, and various statements, like if/while/for, and so on. Your question is unclear, as a C++ question.

Comment: add an edge to the adjacency list . That is what I meant, sorry

Comment: You can't have an `edge` array with no dimension - embedded in the middle of your `struct` - then start reading and writing it as if it had elements.  Yikes.  I suggest you use a graph library like boost::graph or lemon.

Comment: Well, there's nothing called an "adjacency list" in C++ either, so to a C++ programmer the term "adjacency list" doesn't mean anything, either. If you'd like to get some help with C++ then you need to ask a ***specific*** question related to C++, the programming language.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I am not allowed to use any other library

Comment: If you have artificial constraints, it's a good idea to explain that in your question.  Are you allowed to use `std::vector`?  Seperately, `int index(string h)` doesn't have a `return` statement for when there's no match.  You should compile with warnings (e.g. g++ -Wall, or clang++ -Wall) and at least try to fix them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am creating a graph data structure using an adjacency list

Comment: @TonyDelroy my major concern is with the function I named con_add(). the index(string h) works just fine. the major problem is with my con_add()

Comment: *"the index(string h) works just fine"* - it has [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you call it for an string that doesn't find a match, which probably means your program crashes or produces wrong results.  Strange definition of just fine.  `con_add()` looks in `edge`, which as I've already told you doesn't even exist - it's a 0 element array.  You actually read from it without having even tried to store anything in it.  I've no idea how you thought that would work, so it's hard to suggest a fix.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I have rectified the index function but I am still not able to add the edge in connections()

Comment: Again, `start=edge[i].start_ver; end= edge[i].end_ver;` is wrong - you can't index into an array with 0 elements.  `start` and `end` are values you read from file - surely you want to *store* them somewhere not overwrite them without having used them?  Did you mean to do something like `edge[i].start_ver = start;`?  If so, you will need to `new` an array of `std::string`s, much as you've done for `head` and `person`.